# Is there a way to do "intraWord" text navigation in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard

On Windows, **Ctrl+Right Arrow** will move the text cursor from one "word" to the next.  While working with Xcode on the Mac, they extended that so that **Option+Right Arrow** will move the cursor to the beginning of the next *subword*.  For example, if the cursor was at the beginning of the word `myCamelCaseVar` then hitting **Option+Right Arrow** will put the cursor at the first `C`.  This was an amazingly useful feature that I haven't found in a Windows editor.

Do you know of any way to do this in Visual Studio (perhaps with an Add-In)?

I'm currently using pretty old iterations of Visual Studio (Visual Basic 6.0 and [Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++)), although I'm interested to know if the more modern releases can do this, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper has a "[Camel Humps](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#CamelHumps)" feature that lets you do this.